# How to clear footer for the last page?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

In the preamble of an exam I am creating, I currently have:

```
%headers, footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} %header
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % your new footer definitions here
\rfoot{\large \bf{GO ON TO NEXT PAGE}}
```

Of course, I'd like for "**GO ON TO THE NEXT PAGE**" to be removed on the last page. Is there any way I can do this?

**Edit/Update**: By the way, at the end, I ended up approaching this problem differently than what the answers below provided because the document went through many changes in the last day or so (from me asking questions on this website). I ended up defining a page style:

```
\fancypagestyle{laststyle}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{STOP}}
}
```

and putting `\thispagestyle{laststyle}` where I wanted it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
\AtEndDocument{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

to the document preamble. Alternatively, replace `empty` with whichever page style you want to match your other document components. What should also work is to use

```
\AtEndDocument{\rfoot{}}
```

to clear the `r`ight `foot`er.

Here is a minimal example showing the usage and output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%headers, footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} %header
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % your new footer definitions here
\rfoot{\large \textbf{GO ON TO NEXT PAGE}}
\lfoot{\large\thepage}
\AtEndDocument{\rfoot{}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

---

The above may not work in all instances, as it depends on when the pages are shipped out. One may use some help from [`pageslts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts)'s `VeryLastPage` label and [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) to extract the value:

```
\usepackage{pageslts,refcount}

%headers, footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} %header
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % your new footer definitions here
\rfoot{\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{VeryLastPage}=\value{page}\else\large \textbf{GO ON TO NEXT PAGE}\fi}
\lfoot{\large\thepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: You're being lucky; try with `\lipsum[1-48]a\\a\\a\\a`

Comment: @egreg: Corrected using [`pageslts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts)'s `VeryLastPage` label. Probably similar to your [`zref-totpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) approach.

Answer (score 5):

The safest method is checking if the page is *really* the last one, which can be obtained with `zref-totpages`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-totpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%headers, footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} %header
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % your new footer definitions here
\fancyfoot[R]{\ifnum\value{page}=\ztotpages\else\large \textbf{GO ON TO NEXT PAGE}\fi}
\fancyfoot[L]{\large\thepage}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-48]
a\\
a\\
a\\
a
\end{document}
```

The example, taken from Werner's answer, fails with his code: both page 9 and 10, with the simple `\AtEndDocument{\rfoot{}}` would have an empty footer.

Instead of `\lfoot` and `\rfoot` I prefer `\fancyfoot` and `\fancyhead`; they're almost equivalent, but the “newer” ones are better.

Comment: Is not `\AtEndDocument{\rfoot{}}` equivalent to `\rfoot{}\end{document}`? If yes, why does it fail?

Comment: @Sigur The page breaking mechanism is asynchronous; in the (admittedly a bit contrived) example, the last four line paragraph is typeset and the page break has not yet been decided when `\end{document}` is scanned. Now `\end{document}` executes `\rfoot{}` and so this setting applies also to the last but one page, because TeX decides to break the page after having performed that action.

Comment: This is a good answer, it gives the right idea, however in my case I had to use `\ifnum\thepage=\numpages`